# How to change String to Int in Json Parser in scala

Tags: scala, play-json

I am using Play JsPath

```
val jsonrecord = "{\"id\":111,\"zip\":\"123\"}"

case class record(id: Int, name: Int)

def validZip(name:String) = name.matches("""^[0-9]*$""")

def jsonextraction(json: JsValue): record = {

    implicit val jsonread: Reads[record] = (
      (JsPath \ "id").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "zip").read[String](validZip)
      ) (record.apply _)
    val result = json.as[record]
    result 
}
```

how to convert `name` field string to Int 
json input field is zip is quotes like string "123".

I trying to remove quotes and make it Integer ,

checking empty values it should not be empty , if it is empty trying to throw exception like  bad record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just map to an integer like so:

```
(JsPath \ "zip").read[String].map(_.toInt)
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._

case class record(id: Int, name: Int)

object record {
  implicit val jsonread: Reads[record] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "zip").read[String](pattern("""^[0-9]*$""".r)).map(_.toInt)
  )(record.apply _)
}

object PlayJson extends App {
  val jsonrecord = """{ "id": 111, "zip": "123" }"""
  println(Json.parse(jsonrecord).as[record])
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Its working but its not checking empty values,

Comment: I trying to check empty values also for the zip field also

Comment: @Nathon Replace `*` with `+` in the regex like so: `"""^[0-9]+$""".r`